# Using a file input as stdin for a shell script does not work

Tags: linux, shell, input, stdin

I have the following script code:

**test.sh**

```
echo "BEGIN"
while read CMD <&1; do
    [ -z "$CMD" ] && continue
    case "$CMD" in
    start)
            echo "get_start"
            ;;
    stop)
            echo "get_stop"
            ;;
    *)
            echo "get_uknown_command"
            ;;
    esac
    echo "END";
done
```

When I run it with:

```
$./test.sh <input.txt
```

I get my script locked

**input.txt**

```
start
stop
sthh
```

Why my script is locked? How I can fix that?

BTW: If I enter the data manually then the script will not lock.

Comment: Don't read from stdout (&1). Try `&0`.

Comment: @ott yes indded that was the error in the script. `&0` means stdin and `&1` means stdout. thnak you for the comment. make it an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Why the redirect anyway? Just `while read CMD; do` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second line is incorrect, and overly complex anyway. The [file descriptors](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#FDREF) for `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are `0`, `1`, and `2`, respectively, so to read from `stdin` you'd want to have

```bsh
while read CMD <&0; do
```

However, since `stdin` is the default input for `read`,

```
while read CMD; do
```

is really the simplest way to go. This way, you can manually enter the commands, or use redirection on the command line to read from a file.